# Can't install Steam dependencies on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt, steam

I just upgraded Kubuntu with an iso, trying to install Steam i get this:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading > state
>   information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This > may
>   mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are >
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not >
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following >
>   information may help to resolve the situation: The following >
>   packages have unmet dependencies. steam:i386 : Depends: >
>   libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed > Recommends:
>   nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable E: Unable to
>   correct problems, you have held broken > packages.

========================================================================

I had newer Mesa drivers from Paulo's PPA, i uninstalled 'em and removed the PPA, then reinstalled Mesa.
I tried this: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing newer version of Mesa with the oibaf's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
Probably the issue was generated to begin with because i left the Paulo's PPA for Mesa after upgrading to 19.04, i'm not sure. I hope it helps someone else.